# ReactJS - push json into state array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm simply trying to append a `json` created dynamically into an `array` that lives inside the `state`.
The only way that I've found till now is to use concat, because push doesn't work.

```
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            list: []
        }
        this.add = this.add.bind(this)
    }

    add(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        var task = document.getElementById('task').value
        var json = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({key: task, item: task}))
        this.setState({list: this.state.list.concat(json)}) // WORKS
        // this.setState({list: this.state.list.push(json)}) // DOESN'T WORK

        console.log(this.state.list)
        document.getElementById('task').value = ''

    }
```

That works, but I don't understand why I have an empty array in console after the first item it's created. I've read how concat works, but obviously I missed something. Why I can't push an object inside my this.list array?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) otherwise create a **new array** and return it.

The [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) returns **the new length of the array**, which means a number, which means **NOT** what you want to set to `state.list`. That's why it didn't work.

> why I have an empty array in console

[From the docs](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate): **`setState()` does not immediately mutate `this.state`** but creates a pending state transition. Accessing `this.state` after calling this method can potentially return the existing value. That's why you are getting the empty array in the console.

And one more thing, don't mutate your `state` directly. If you call `state.list.push(...)`, your changes will not be maintained by React and will be discarded if you call `setState` later. So it's a good thing to use `concat`.

Comment: Right, but do you know why I have an empty array in console after I create the first element? I expected to see the element I've just created

Comment: From the docs: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate: **`setState()` does not immediately mutate `this.state`** but creates a pending state transition. Accessing `this.state` after calling this method can potentially return the existing value. That's why you are getting the empty array in the console. In another words, `setState` run asynchronously.

Comment: I'm wondering if my code could be a good approach or exists a better/cleaner way to append data into an array

Comment: Tips: don't use `document.getElementById`, use state and props. You might want to read this article to clearly know how to work in React: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html

Comment: the answer is totally misleading the problem is not what array.push return the problem is about mutation so react can know the difference between the state previous and current state changes also this.setState accept a callback function that can be used to know if the state change process is finished.

Comment: @fareednamrouti Not sure if you have read the question carefully, I am pretty positive that the problem is OP is setting a wrong state value because of misunderstanding how array.push works. Correct me where I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

`this.state` is immutable and has to be changed only via the `setState()` function.

From the docs:

> NEVER mutate this.state directly, as calling setState() afterwards may
>   replace the mutation you made. Treat this.state as if it were
>   immutable. setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but
>   creates a pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling
>   this method can potentially return the existing value.

So, the best way to do this is to replace the array in `this.state` by a new array, and not try to push/modify it.

```
var newState = Object.assign({}, this.state); // Clone the state obj in newState
newState[arrayKey].push(newItem);             // modify newState
this.setState(newState);                      // setState()
```

Answer (score 0):

`Array.prototype.push()` returns the new length property of the object upon which the method was called.

See:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push#Returns

Comment: Damn, TrungDQ beat me to it :)