# how to setState to key inside a record in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

hai i am getting trouble when i try like this, i want to setState to key inside a record
**Example:**

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data:{"firstName":"XXXXX",lastName:"YYYYY",Rank:1}
    }
}
```

i declare this in initial state,here i want to change only particular key like rank,for that i wrote like this:

> this.Setstate({data.Rank:2})

it gives an Error
any one give me suggestions how to resolve it, any help much appreciated

Comment: what's the error? `this.Setstate` supposed to be `this.setState`

Comment: unexpected token ({data.Rank:2})

Comment: as Raspberry mentioned, please check whether you set the `data` in `getInitialState`

Comment: yah i declare it in initial state only

Comment: please post your `getInitialState` method in the question  for better reference

Answer (score 2):

Please go through this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/34384198/3563619

You have to extend `this.state` to a `newState`, make changes in `newState` and and then `setState(newState)`

```
newState = Object.assign({}, this.state);    // clone this.state in a new object newState
newState.data.Rank = 2;                      // make changes to newState
this.setState(newState);                     // setState()
```

You can make any type and any number of modifications to `newState` and then use `setState()` without having any doubt over what you are doing.

Comment: i.e i need to declare a dummy record and set that record to initially assigned  record?

Comment: Yes. It is the safest way to do and you can keep on doing modifications to your dummy without being worried of `this.state` immutability.

Comment: other than this, is there any alternate way?

Answer (score 1):

You are setting state not correct.

If you have a component:

```
React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(){
    return {
      data: {"firstName":"XXXXX",lastName:"YYYYY",Rank:1}
    };
  }
});
```

You need to do:

```
var data = this.state.data;
data.Rank = 2;

this.setState({
  data: data
});
```

Comment: he wants to make changes to `this.state.data.Rank`. The above answer makes changes to `this.state.rank`. Please modify.

Comment: yah i want to change particular key

Comment: if the initial `state` is in the format `return { 'data': data };`, then `this.setState({ data.Rank: 2})` should work.

Comment: what about the format as like above? I declared it in constructors